# Need to find a common element between mysql rows

Tags: mysql, forms, joomla

Let me start by saying that I am new to mysql and have searched on this site and others for a solution that will work for me. I've gotten fairly close (I think), but can't seem to find a solution.

I'm working on a Joomla site using RSForms software. I need to search a table where one row contains FirstName, another row contains LastName, and another row contains Email. Ultimately, I am looking for SubmissionId that is common to all 3. SubmissionId is a number generated by some form software that groups all of the form submission's elements by this id. I need to search for this id that is common to all 3. Each of the 3 elements may contain duplicates of the search. For instance, searching for the first name "John" will likely produce multiple results. I want to find the SubmissionId that matches "John" and last name "Doe" and email "johndoe@gmail.com" so I can use that to look up other information. It is also possible that there could be multiple matches for "John", "Doe", and johndoe@gmail.com".

I've tried many variations of the following (with/without ANY) and putting the results into an array and counting through each element. I've only had success in acquiring the first instance of "John".

```
$getresults = $db->setQuery("SELECT SubmissionId FROM my_table_values WHERE FormId = '$formid' AND FieldValue = '$fname' AND SubmissionId = ANY
    (SELECT SubmissionId FROM my_table_values WHERE FormId = '$formid' AND FieldValue = '$lname' AND SubmissionId = ANY
    (SELECT SubmissionId FROM my_table_values WHERE FormId = '$formid' AND FieldValue = '$email' ))");

---SubmissionValueId---|---FormId---|---SubmissionId---|---FieldName---|---Field‌​‌​‌​Value---
---------18192---------|-----20-----|-------5462-------|-----Email-----|---johndoe@gmail.com---
---------18193---------|-----20-----|-------5462-------|-----FName-----|---John---
---------18194---------|-----20-----|-------5462-------|-----LName-----|---Doe---
```

Comment: could you show your table `my_table_values ` structure please? and sample of data if possible

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a query that joins `my_table_values` with *itself,* even two times, to create something that can then be checked.  For instance ... *(fair warning: extemporaneous coding)* ...

> `select A.submission_id from my_table_values A inner join my_table_values B using (SubmissionID) inner join my_table_values C using (SubmissionID) where (A.formID="email" and A.fieldValue= "foo@bar.com") and (B.formID="lastname" and B.fieldValue= "bar") and (C.formID="first name" and C.fieldValue="bletch")`

You will need to `examine` that query to see *(a)* if the SQL processor accepts it, and *(b)* what sort of execution-plan it came up with.  Preferably, all of the fields should be indexed.  You need to see that it plans to *use* the indexes each time to narrow the list of possibilities, and that it plans to use the most-selective field (e.g. "email") first.

(The `using (fieldname)` syntax is specific to MySQL.  You might need to use `on` to do the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$getresults = $db->setQuery("
     SELECT 
       MAX(IF(FieldValue = '$fname',SubmissionId, NULL) as fnameId,
       MAX(IF(FieldValue = '$lname',SubmissionId, NULL) as lnameId,
       MAX(IF(FieldValue = '$email',SubmissionId, NULL) as emailId
     FROM my_table_values 
     WHERE FormId = '$formid' 
     GROUP BY FormId");
```

Comment: I get a syntax error...
Error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as fnameId, MAX(IF(FieldValue = 'xxxxx', SubmissionId, NULL) as lnameId' at line 2
I thought that there should've been closing parentheses after the IF statement, but that didn't change the error.

Comment: Missing some closing parentheses. That's all.

Comment: @Alex    After further testing, I do see that this returns a SubmissionId, but it only returns 1 of them. I failed to mention in my original post (now edited) that there is the possibility of there being multiple SubmissionIds that will match the name/email search.